# How can iterate json string in java

Tags: java, json

how can iterate folliwng string using json in java?
please help me to resolve

```
{
   "doc": {
      "info": {
         "calaisRequestID": "99bb6d1b-4cd4-f707-15a1-21d5b7e5fe06",
         "id": "http://id.opencalais.com/PtEjIbIEZJnsbQ6Dg7FxDg",
         "docDate": "2017-02-06 06:29:58.538"
      },
      "meta": {
         "contentType": "text/raw",
         "signature": "digestalg-1|FQYcf/+Yws22W7+jhh+/DXJkVVw=|Gq8H8eU8ouqthpHXVjEqNRPesF1Kqh1SVB0SColRFoxQ2t5cxU9NyA==",
         "language": "English"
      }
   },
   "http://d.opencalais.com/dochash-1/089ef2a6-c33e-32b7-bbd4-cb078da19bd8/cat/1": {
      "_typeGroup": "topics",
      "name": "Business_Finance"
   },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some json library like Gson to convert this string into an object of the same hierarchy.